# Post-Ugrade Problem with 3.3.1

Tags: php

Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on null in ~/system/ee/legacy/libraries/Session.php on line 398

The $member object (re: $member = ee('Model')->get('Member', $member_id)->first();) is null.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this same issue and after a good few hours of debugging, I found the issue was because the member didn't have an entry in the **exp_member_data** table.

Just add a new row to the **exp_member_data** table with the member_id you're logging in with (*search the exp_members table to find the correct member_id if need be*) and you should be all set.

You don't need to enter any other information in the row to resolve the issue.

Comment: Huge help! Thank you for posting this fix.